# Как вывести все типы полей?

Tags: ado, delphi, delphi-7

Добрый день!

Как вывести типы полей в неизвестной таблице. Имеется *Excel*-файл *2.xls*. Чтобы обратиться к нему в виде SQL запроса, использую *ADOQuery1*. Пишем

```
ADOQuery1.ConnectionString:='Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=2.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;Persist Security Info=False';
```

Файл *2.xls* находиться в папке с проектом. Далее

```
ADOQuery1.Active:=False;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('select * from [Sheet1$]');
ADOQuery1.Active:=True;
```

Высветилась все таблица. Первые строки в каждом столбце стали именем поля. 
**Sheet1$** - имя листа, только без знака (**$**). Добавляем

```
for i:=0 to ADOQuery1.FieldCount-1 do
ComboBox1.Items.Add(ADOQuery1.FieldList.Fields[i].FieldName);
```

Высветил все имена полей таблицы. Но как вывести все типы этих полей?

Благодарю за внимание!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i:=0 to ADOQuery1.FieldCount-1 do
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(ADOQuery1.FieldList.Fields[i].FieldName+' '+                                                 FieldTypeNames[ADOQuery1.Fields[i].DataType]);
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! То что нужно.